# Is "The Conspiracy" based on a real secret society?

Tags: realism, the-conspiracy

For lack of better options, I watched the movie "The Conspiracy" and in the end there was a strange brotherhood-type ritual where they placed a cows head on an unsuspecting victim and attacked him (whether or not he survived was open to interpretation).

Is this based on a real tradition or club that is operative to some degree?

Comment: If that was based on anything remotely real then that is hilarious

Answer (score 4):

I believe it is based off of Bohemian Grove, which is located in California.

> In mid-July each year, Bohemian Grove hosts a two-week, three-weekend encampment of some of the most prominent men in the world

The event features rituals and ceremonies similar to those seen in the film.

Here's one of the rituals a journalist secretly recorded: